# Would URLs with query strings have better SEO with a filename too?

Tags: seo, url, filenames

I'm writing a single-page application.

The navigation links look like this:

```
http://example.com/?home

http://example.com/?contact-us

http://example.com/?about-us
```

In terms of SEO, would this be improved by adding a file name such as:

```
http://example.com/index.html?contact-us
```

Comment: *...would this be improved by adding a file name...* No. Makes no difference at all.

Comment: `index.html` is a particularly poor filename for SEO.  It conveys no extra meaning for search engines.   The URLs usually work either with or without it, leading to duplicate content issues for SEO.

Comment: I would prefer the cleaner URL without the index.html as they tend to have higher click through rates.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the file name for your single page application is specifically `index.html`, rather than some other file same, such as `single-page-application.html`, whether or not you include the file name in your links should have **no impact on SEO**.

I would, however, recommend using `https` if you aren't already, as this will be beneficial for SEO.

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html

You can get a free SSL/TLS Certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).